# previous file is being disappear when clicking input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, input

I am creating a web app in which I want to allow my users to select multiple files,

when my user select multiple files at a time it is working fine but when the user re-select again the previous files disappear,

here is my input field

```
<input type="file" id="uploadMultipleFiles" multiple />
```

I want my user to select multiple file and allow them to click multiple time without loosing the previous file selection

here is a [JSFiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/a7j1hpL5/),

I can use javascript or jquery if necessary

Hope I explain this question properly

Comment: So when they close the choosing window and re-open it, to have what they had selected still selected? If that's so, then you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that working using the JavaScript. You have to push the selected file in an array. when the user submit the form, you have to send the files to the server using ajax.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('uploadMultipleFiles');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var allFiles = [];

input.addEventListener('change', function(evnt){
 for(var i=0; i<input.files.length; i++){
   allFiles.push(input.files[i])
  }
})

btn.addEventListener('click', function(evnt){
  console.log('Loading Files')
  allFiles.forEach( function(file){
    console.log(file.name)
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="uploadMultipleFiles" multiple />
<br><br><br>
<button id="btn">
  Console All Files
</button>
```